# Drupal 7 - template file location in subtheme for panel page?

Tags: templates, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am trying to add a panel page template to Drupal 7 but it is not picking up.

I have added this to my subtheme's template.php:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  // if this is a panel page, add template suggestions
  if($panel_page = page_manager_get_current_page()) {

    // add a generic suggestion for all panel pages
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__panel';

    // add the panel page machine name to the template suggestions
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $panel_page['name'];

    //add a body class for good measure
    $body_classes[] = 'page-panel';
  }
}
```

And then I have placed page--panel.tpl.php in my subtheme's templates folder.
(Full path: /profiles/mytheme/themes/custom/mytheme/templates/page--panel.tpl.php)

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear Cache ( using flush cache at left top admin menu) and try to save theme once in Appeareance  section